# onClick doesn't work on Button Style Component in Mobil View

Tags: reactjs, mobile, onclick, styled-components

I have a styled.button that works perfectly on desktop view, but when on my desktop I toggle to mobile view it doesn't work at all.

Button:

```
const DateElement = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.primary ? '#DEE2FF' : '#696B86')};
  color: ${(props) => (props.primary ? 'black' : '#dedee4')};
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  user-select: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(20, 79, 118, 0.2);
  & :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  & :focus {
    display: none;
  }
  ${(theme) => theme.theme.breakpoints.down('sm')} {
    padding: 3px;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
  }
`;
```

render:

```
return (
        <DateElement
          key={date.getTime()}
          primary={isSelected}
          onClick={() => handleClick(date)}
          className={clsx({
            [classes.crossed]: date.getTime() + endTimeMilli < today.getTime(),
            [classes.containerWidth]: dates.length > 4,
          })}
        >
          <Typography className={classes.date}>{getWeekDay(date)}</Typography>
          <Typography className={classes.month}>{getMonth(date)}</Typography>
          <Typography className={classes.day}>{date.getDate()}</Typography>
        </DateElement>
      );
```

What is the issue?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up fixing it changing the styled component from button to div, I just changed it and it work, I still don't understand why or how but it worked.

```
const DateElement = styled.div`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you are using `theme.theme`?

`${(theme) => theme.theme.breakpoints.down('sm')} {..`

I could be wrong but not how it usually looks according to the docs: https://mui.com/customization/breakpoints/

Comment: It was created with Styled Components not Material UI